# ERROR in Symbol InputText declared in .. on angular build prod

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to export the primeng modules from a file. On build test I'm not having error on test build but on prod build i am having this error;

```
ERROR in Symbol InputText declared in Q:/Projects/LAST_BOSS/boss-web-ui/node_modules/primeng/inputtext/inputtext.d.ts is not exported from @models (import into Q:/Projects/LAST_BOSS/boss-web-ui/src/app/admin/form-generator/index/index.component.ts)
```

File that i exported the modules

```
export {ListboxModule} from "primeng/listbox";
export {ConfirmDialogModule} from 'primeng/confirmdialog';
export {ConfirmationService} from 'primeng/api';
export {TableModule} from "primeng/table";
export {DropdownModule} from "primeng/dropdown";
export {ButtonModule} from "primeng/button";
export {InputTextModule} from "primeng/inputtext";
export {CardModule} from "primeng/card";
export {InputSwitchModule} from "primeng/inputswitch";
export {ProgressBarModule} from "primeng/progressbar";
export {PanelModule} from "primeng/panel";
export {ToolbarModule} from "primeng/toolbar";
export {SplitButtonModule} from "primeng/splitbutton";
export {FieldsetModule} from "primeng/fieldset";
export {TabViewModule} from "primeng/tabview";
export {KeyFilterModule} from "primeng/keyfilter";
```

File path on tsconfig.ts;

```
"paths": {
      "@app": [
        "src/app"
      ],
      "@app/*": [
        "src/app/*"
      ],
      "@admin": [
        "src/app/admin"
      ],
      "@admin/*": [
        "src/app/admin/*"
      ],
      "@models": [
        "src/app/admin/models"
      ],
      "@models/*": [
        "src/app/admin/models/*"
      ],
}
```

I am waiting for the answers for fix that issue.

Comment: search **InputText** in your project?

Comment: i have used  **InputText** in a lot of place in my project

Answer (score 0):

**InputText** user in **html** must be declared inside the corresponding **.ts** file.

Comment: I am not directly import from the node_modules/primeng, first i am trying to export those primeng modules from a file then import into corresponfing angular module for using as component.